# How do rules of Ben Schiderman apply/violate?

Tags: usability, user-research, research, guidelines

I read about 8 Golden Rules of Ben Schiderman which are as follows:

1. Strive for consistency
2. Permit easy reversal of actions
3. Offer informative feedback
4. Enable shortcuts for frequent users
5. Provide dialog for closure
6. Support internal locus of control
7. Provide simple error handling
8. Reduce short term memory load

I was trying to find examples to know how it is applied but I found an exercise instead. I tried to solve it but I am not sure if my answers are correct. The question is for each of the statement given below specify which of Ben Schneiderman’s Principle is violated or followed:

1. When searching a friend, Facebook provides the profile picture along with the names of the friends
   My Answer: Profile pictures are some-what used as feedback so "Offer Informative feedback" is followed here.
2. The user can place the alarm icon on the main screen which is normally available under the menu options.
   My Answer: By reading the rules I thought that by shortcuts Ben means keyboard shortcuts but in this case moving the icon to main screen seems like "Enable shortcuts for frequent users" is being followed here.
3. When an application is about to close with some unsaved data, the system responds “do you want to save your work” 
   My Answer: Simple error handling
4. The website constantly displays percentage of data uploaded as you are uploading large amount of data on a website.
   My Answer: Informative feedback
5. The Adobe photoshop application has provided a toolbar for commonly used tools.
   My Answer: Again like (2), "Enable shortcuts for frequent users".

Comment: Q3 feels like it could also be "Provide dialog for closure"?

Comment: As far as I have read, the closure should have some psychological response.

Comment: Sure, after reading through them again, your answer of error handling is probably closest.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with you on all but number 3. I feel like the pop-up window asking if you're sure fits the "Permit easy reversal of actions" principle. Attempting to close a file isn't necessarily an error, however if the user has clicked it by accident, it allows them to change their mind.

Simple error handling does fit, in a way, but I believe that the second rule is a better fit.